# C++ conditional giving an error

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Take a look at this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using ld = long double;

template<int i>
struct A {
    static_assert(false,"");
    constexpr static int value = 3;
};

template<int i>
struct B {
    constexpr static int value = i*i*i;
};

template<int i>
struct CheckVal {
    constexpr static int value = conditional<i == 1,A,B><3>::value;
};
```

This is supposed to terminate the compilation if a `1` is passed to `CheckVal`, but I'm getting the following error on compilation, no matter what is passed to `CheckVal`:

```
error: use of class template 'A' requires template arguments
    constexpr static ld value = conditional<i == 1,A,B><3>::value;
```

What is the problem here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The only place, where you use `A`, is inside `conditional<>`.

`A` requires a template argument, namely `template<int i>`.

So, instead of `A`, you must say `A<i>` or `A<3>` or ... same for `B`.
And finally, you must remove `<3>` as your compiler will tell you:

```
template<int i>
struct CheckVal {
    constexpr static int value = conditional<i == 1, A<i>, B<i> >::value;
};
```

---

However, the compiler (at least g++) will fail with

> error: static assertion failed:
>        static_assert(false,"");
>        ^

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `static_assert` will always trigger, so not sure what was the purpose of it. If you comment it out, this is what you need to change in `CheckVal` to make it work:

```
template<int i>
struct CheckVal
{
    constexpr static int value = std::conditional<i == 1, A<3>, B<3>>::type::value;
};
```

`std::conditional` will select either `A<3>` or `B<3>` depending on condition, then you first need to return the type `::type` and only then you can get the `::value` member

Demo: https://ideone.com/tozaYr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve but isn't this much simpler construct sufficient?

```
template<int i>
struct CheckVal {
    static_assert(i != 1,"");
};
```